# Include TikZ element inside tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm making a graphic representation of the results in a competition. Each team has gotten points in five different categories, and I want them represented in a bar per team, two sets of points above and three below the x-axis.

An integral part of this is a command that creates the parts of the bar. Right now basically a rectangle of height `<points>/100` and width `.5`, and `<points>` written at position `(.25,<points>/200)`. The following command produces the right output, but I want to be able to define where it goes.

```
\newcommand{\myrect}[1]{
    \path[draw](0,0) rectangle +(.5,#1/100);
    \node at (.25,#1/200) {#1};
}
```

I want to be able to write something like this MW(ish)E:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\myrect}[1]{
 \path[draw](0,0) rectangle +(.5,#1/100);
 \node at (0.5,#1/200) {#1};
}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[draw,thick,->] (0,0)--(8,0);
  \path[draw,thick,<->] (0,-3)--(0,3);
  \myrect{86} at (.25,0);
  \myrect{74} at (.25,.86);
  \myrect{91} at (.25,-.91); %and so on
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I know that this is probably basic TikZ, but everything I've seen regarding this seems unnecessarily complicated. How do I best do this?

EDIT:
`pgfplots` seems to be a good solution, and it has gotten me further. As of now, I have

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{swedish}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.9}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar stacked, 
    nodes near coords,
    ylabel={Poäng},
    symbolic x coords={f,e,m},
    enlargelimits=.1,
    xtick={}
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(f,20) (e,50) (m,90)};
\addplot coordinates {(f,70) (e,24) (m,70)};
\addplot coordinates {(f,50) (e,60) (m,10)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

resulting in 
[image: Result]

What I really want is something like [image: Wanted]

That is, a new stacked bar graph below the x axis. Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: I would look at using `pgfplots` for this.

Comment: You can plot these with pgfplots so easilly...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\myrect}[3]{
 \path[draw](#2,#3) rectangle +(.6,#1/100);
 \node[anchor=east] at (0.6+#2,#1/200+#3) {#1};
}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[draw,thick,->] (0,0)--(8,0);
  \path[draw,thick,<->] (0,-3)--(0,3);

  \myrect{86}{0}{0}
  \myrect{74}{0.6}{0};
  \myrect{-91}{1.2}{0}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or better this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={\#participants},
    symbolic x coords={Com1,Com2,Com3},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(Com1,86) (Com2,74) (Com3,-91)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

stacked bar graph to have idea how to solve the problem:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
            font=\normalsize\rmfamily,
            line width=1 pt,
            tick style={line width=.6pt}},
        %every node near coord/.append style={anchor=north}
    }
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    axis background/.style={shade,top color=gray,bottom color=white},
    ybar stacked,
    bar width=1cm,
    enlarge x limits=.15,
    ylabel={Count},
    symbolic x coords={
        Com1,Com2,Com3},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    every node near coord/.append style={anchor=south,yshift=-0.25cm,font=\scriptsize}, 
    %nodes near coords align={vertical},
    x tick label style={font=\scriptsize ,text width=2.7cm,align=center},
    ]    \addplot+[black,fill=blue!25!gray] coordinates {
        (Com1,3)
        (Com2,1)
        (Com3,3)

    };
    \addplot+[black,fill=green!25!gray] coordinates {
        (Com1,3)
        (Com2,1)
        (Com3,3)

    };
    \addplot+[black,fill=red!75] coordinates {
        (Com1,3)
        (Com2,1)
        (Com3,3)

    };

    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `pgfplots` seems like a good way to do it. Now it comes down to an easilier describable problem: How do I graph two different stacked bar graphs, one above and one below the x-axis?

Comment: @Gustaphe see the updated post